# How do you delete applications which are stored in your system preferences?

Tags: system-settings

I have these two programs "Fan Control" and "Shades" which I got from the Macupdate website. With other downloads it seems they can simply be dragged nd dropped from the applications folder into the trash and all their history is gone with them. However, Fan Control and Shades seem to be stored somewhere differently and I cannot seem to find a way to delete them. They are seen in the system perferences and no where else now. I deleted them from the download folder and the all files folder but the icon and its function are still there.

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check if its related files are still stored in your computer. Activate Finder, then click Go > Go To Folder, and type in `/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support`, replacing *yourusername* with your username. From here, you will be able to remove your application's related files.

You can remove the application's Preference Pane from System Preferences by opening System Preferences and right-clicking the application's name, and click "Remove Preference Pane".